# Bind view and model in caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, caliburn.micro

How to make caliburn.micro bind child view models to child visuals?

I have an `ObservableCollection` of items in a VM. Items are created manually, caliburn micro is not used. Sometimes they are deserialized from disk.

Views are created by WPF framework through data binding and data templates, I don’t need to search anything, and I don’t want to use ContentControl, I want to instantiate the correct visual tree in XAML, from my data templates there.

Is there a way to force caliburn micro to bind them together without creating neither views nor VMs with it?

Specifically, I want conventions applied automatically, so `<Button x:Name="act" />` from the data template calls `public void act()` on it’s data context when clicked. Like it happens when caliburn micro creates either view or VM using these locators. The data context is set by WPF when it created an item visual from data item.

Comment: Did you try to bind the `cal:Bind.Model` attached property to the `DataContext` like this?: `cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"`. If this is not what you're after, then please provide a minimal code sample of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks, it appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `cal:Bind.Model` attached property of the root element in the `DataTemplate` to the `DataContext` like this:

```
<Grid cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"> ...
```